# Open sets in a Zariski topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I just wanted to ask if there are supposed to be any open discs around points of a variety with this topology because I am looking ahead very much.

Comment: "open disks" is something for metric spaces. Nevertheless, Zariski-open sets are sets where a polynomial is non-zero - and as polynomials are continuous, these sets are also "standard"-open

Comment: I'm trying to define continuous maps for algebraic geometry- so hypothetically if there's a line which is a variety can there be an open set around points on that line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends by what you mean by "disk." Every point indeed has an open neighborhood, but thinking of it as a small disk is probably the wrong intuition. For instance, if you take the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ and look at its open sets, they are of the form $\mathbb{A}^1_k\setminus \{p_1,\ldots, p_r\}$ since the closed subsets of the Zariski topology are the vanishing sets of polynomials (i.e. finite sets of points in $\mathbb{A}^1_k$). In the case where $k$ is infinite - so in particular when $k$ is algebraically closed - any two such open sets intersect. In particular, this topology fails quite badly to be Hausdorff. So, the notion of finding "small" open disks around points does not work.

You can still define continuous maps of algebraic varieties $\varphi:X\to Y$ by requiring that the preimage of open sets of $Y$ be open in $X$.